# How to query MIN value of MAX subquery with two distinct columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table like this:

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+----------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default  |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+----------+
| id            | smallint(6)  | NO   | PRI | NULL     |
| Book          | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | NULL     |
| Chapter       | smallint(6)  | NO   |     | NULL     |
| Paragraph     | smallint(6)  | NO   |     | NULL     |
| Text          | text         | YES  |     | NULL     |
| RevisionNum   | mediumint(9) | NO   | PRI | NULL     |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+----------+
```

mysql> select id,Book,Chapter,Paragraph,RevisionNum FROM MyTable ORDER BY id LIMIT 11;

```
+-----+------+---------+-----------+-------------+
| id  | Book | Chapter | Paragraph | RevisionNum |
+-----+------+---------+-----------+-------------+
|   1 |    1 |       1 |         1 |           0 |
|   1 |    1 |       1 |         1 |           1 |
|   1 |    1 |       1 |         1 |           2 |
|   2 |    1 |       2 |         2 |           0 |
|   2 |    1 |       2 |         2 |           1 |
|   2 |    1 |       2 |         2 |           2 |
|   2 |    1 |       2 |         2 |           3 |
|   3 |    1 |       2 |         3 |           0 |
|   4 |    1 |       2 |         4 |           0 |
|   4 |    1 |       2 |         4 |           1 |
|   5 |    1 |       3 |         5 |           0 |
+-----+------+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

To find a book or chapter which has no unrevised paragraph,
I wish to query either the minimum value of the maximums of
all the distinct id's for that chapter or book, or else in
some fashion determine that no id remains unedited (with a
MAX(RevisionNum) of zero).

Most of my attempts to date have ended in errors like this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Book,RecordNum FROM MyTable
    -> WHERE 0 < ALL (SELECT DISTINCT RecordNum,MAX(RevisionNum) 
                      FROM MyTable 
                      WHERE MAX(RevisionNum) > 0);
                      
ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

...And I wasn't using the "GROUP BY" function at all!

The following query produces results, but simply
gives ALL id's, and does not actually show a unique
set of Book records, as requested.  How could this happen?

SELECT DISTINCT Book,id,MAX(RevisionNum) FROM MyTable GROUP BY id LIMIT 5;

```
+------+----+------------------+
| Book | id | MAX(RevisionNum) |
+------+----+------------------+
|    1 |  1 |               30 |
|    1 |  2 |               16 |
|    1 |  3 |               15 |
|    1 |  4 |               10 |
|    1 |  5 |                9 |
+------+----+------------------+
```

What would the correct query be to give results more like this:

```
+------+-----+-----------------------+
| Book |  id | MIN(MAX(RevisionNum)) |
+------+-----+-----------------------+
|    1 |   5 |                     3 |
|    2 |  17 |                     1 |
|    3 |  33 |                     2 |
|    4 | 147 |                     0 |
|    5 | 225 |                     2 |
+------+-----+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Where do the numbers 17, 33, and so on come from?

Comment: `SELECT RecordNum,MAX(RevisionNum)` requires a `GROUP BY`!

Comment: `GROUP BY` isn't a function; `MAX` (which operates over a group of rows) is.

Comment: @Gordon Those are the actual id's of the paragraphs in question.  The table shown was truncated for the question but has tens of thousands of ids, each with one or more revisions.

Comment: @ScottHunter Whatever "GROUP BY" is or isn't, the error message I receive references a "group function."

Comment: `MAX`, as I pointed out, is a group function; this is what the error is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for two levels of aggregation?

```
select id, book, min(max_revisionnum)
from (select id, book, chapter, paragraph, max(revisionnum) as max_revisionnum
      from mytable
      group by id, book, chapter, paragraph
     ) t
group by id, book;
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you can use:

```
select *
from (select id, book, chapter, paragraph, max(revisionnum) as max_revisionnum,
             row_number() over (partition by book order by max(revisionnum) desc) as seqnum
      from mytable
      group by id, book, chapter, paragraph
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=66cadf7271242c5204a92ec701bbc9cf) is a db<>fiddle.

In older versions of MariaDB, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where (id, book, chapter, paragraph, revisionnum) = (select t2.id, t2.book, t2.chapter, t2.paragraph, t2.revisionnum
                                                     from mytable t2
                                                     where t2.book = t.book
                                                     order by t2.revisionnum desc
                                                     limit 1
                                                    );
```

For this query, try adding an index on `(book, revisionnum desc)`.

Comment: I am looking for one unique result per book showing the id with the lowest RevisionNum.  If a paragraph has never yet been edited, it will still have only its original id with a RevsionNum of 0.  I want a list of all the Book's which still have unedited paragraphs.

Comment: I think this answer gives the same results as:

SELECT DISTINCT id,Book,MAX(RevisionNum) FROM MyTable GROUP BY id;

And this amounts to a listing of all possible id's (thousands in my case).

Comment: @Polyhat . . . Your comment is much clearer than your question.  I added an edit to the answer to show what you want.

Comment: Your edited version balks at the "partition" point.  `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by Book `... is there anything obvious there that might be corrected?  I've never used `partition` before.

Comment: @Polyhat . . . .You must be using a very old version of MariaDB.  That database has supported window functions for several years.

Comment: I wish that were the answer.
`MariaDB> select version();` gives me `10.0.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`.  Could it be something with the `over` part perhaps?

Comment: @Polyhat . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  MariaDB started supporting window functions in version 10.2.0, which was released in 2016.  You are using a branch off an old stable release, 10.0, so it doesn't support window functions.

Comment: The query you suggested for the "old" MariaDB ran, but I'm still trying to figure out if it gave me what I wanted.  It returned dozens of rows and every column in the table, including text columns, thus burying the column (RevisionNum) I was focused on, and it took (1 hour 22 min 18.36 sec).  Obviously, this is useless as a quick statistical reference.  I would be extremely surprised if there were no better way to query the table, and the "new" features should not be necessary for such a simple result.